# Centering Navbar Content with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a web page that uses Bootstrap. I am trying to add a fixed navbar. This navbar will have three sections. I want the left content to be left-aligned, the center content to be center-aligned and the right content to be aligned to the right. Basically, I need it to looks like this:

```
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| Hello                 |    item 1 | item 2    |               contact |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

In an attempt to do this, I've written the following code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" style="background-color:#000;">
  <div class="navbar-brand pull-left">Hello</div>
  <ul style="list-inline">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>|</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="pull-right">
    contact  
  </div>
</nav>
```

The "Hello" is properly aligned. The "contact" is properly aligned. However, I can't seem to figure out how to center the `ul` within the navbar. Can somebody please share their CSS mojo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `col-` and `text-align` like this:

```css
* {
    color: #fff;
}
.list-inline {
    display: inline-block;
}
.left-content{
    text-align: left;
}
.center-content{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
}
.right-content{
    text-align: right;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" style="background-color:#000;">
    <div class="navbar-brand left-content col-xs-2">Hello</div>
    <div class="center-content col-xs-8">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right-content col-xs-2">contact</div>
</nav>
```

You can change the cols according to what you need, check out this fore more info http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp